# What is the "PMEM limit" and "EP number"?

Tags: linux, wordpress, woocommerce, isapi

I'm running a wordpress/woocommerce website on a shared hosting.

The website crashes a lot, and I'm getting following error in logs:

> [Tue Feb 27 08:52:39.512155 2024] [lsapi:error] [pid 1596660:tid 140182791464704] [client 66.249.79.136:48319] [host www.mydomain.online] Error on sending request(GET /some/url/ HTTP/1.1); uri(/index.php) content-length(0): ReceiveAckHdr: nothing to read from backend (LVE ID 1202), check http://docs.cloudlinux.com/mod_lsapi_troubleshooting.html

I've read the documentation and found out that this should solve the problem:

> These errors occurs when the amount of PMEM limits is incommensurable with the number of EP. Increase PMEM limits or decrease EP number for the user UID.

Problem is, I have no idea how I can do this. Anyone who can explain this more clearly?

Comment: You are hitting your memory limit from your configuration. If you are unsure how to solve this issue ask your hosting to assist you. Of course this may happen due to bad query , plugin conflicts , getting an endless loop and so on. Just sharing error that you have hit your limit doesnt help and needs more debuging from your side or hire someone to look into it.